# Use timepicker plugin on dynamically created inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use [bootstrap-material-datetimepicker](https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker) as a plugin to pick up time in my form.

The problem is that this form is dynamically loaded from server so it doesn't do anything when user clicks on `input` field. It works correctly only if the form isn't dynamically loaded.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ...
        $('#id_time_from').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({date: false, format: "HH:mm"});
```

The problem is that the plugin window is not being called directly through some `click` event, instead you do:

```
Element.bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({date: false, format: "HH:mm"});
```

How can I make it work for dynamically generated `input`s?

Comment: What do you mean by *the plugin window is not being called directly through some `click` event*?

Comment: It is not initialised by click event Element.click(...  but this way: Element.bootstrapMaterialDatePicker() so I can't do $(document).on('click',Element....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the form, at the same time you attach the `bootstrapMaterialDatePicker` to the form element. i,e load your script element along with the dynamic form loading. That should work fine.

Eg.

```
<form>
 ...
 ...
 <button id="id_time_from"> </button>
<script> 
$('#id_time_from').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({date: false, format: "HH:mm"});
</script>
 ...
 ...
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but I added the line after $(get)... instead of inside the .done() function